# PHP PDO select entry from database that matches a variable

Tags: php, pdo

I've looked at some of the other answers on here regarding this but I keep getting errors so here goes.

Whenver a user visits the site, they are asked to provide their name and are assigned a random integer. When they hit submit to enter their name the form gets submitted and saved to the database and the user gets redirected back to the main page. If the random number once again matches a number saved in the database, that name gets displayed.

I have no problem inserting values into the database but I am having some issues retrieving them back out.

My connection to the database is fine, just left the values generic for the purpose of this question.

```
<?php
    $min=1;
    $max=100;
    $rand_number = rand($min,$max);

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        //Set PDO Error Mode to Exception
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        //Prepare SQL
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("select nickname from users where number=".$rand_number);
        $stmt->execute();

        if (!$stmt) {
            foreach($result as $row) {
                    echo $row['nickname'];
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

I'm getting an error that something is wrong around the part where I'm matching the query to the variable.

Comment: And that error message would be....?

Comment: You insert the data in the database using a random number, and now you're trying to select from the DB with another random number. See the problem? It's two random numbers. How are they supposed to be the same?

Comment: Where does `$result` come from? And is your `if` statement correct - "if the query fails, then loop through a result set" ?

Comment: post the complete code, `$result` is undefined on the current posted question

Comment: You can't have `try` without `catch` or `finally` (PHP 5.5). I suggest you ignore exception handling for now

Comment: @scrowler good catch, I glossed over the `if (!$stmt)` part. With exception mode on though, the code would never reach that part if `prepare` failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I really see missing is where you would fetch the data. You can either use one of the `fetch*` methods of `PDOStatement` or simply iterate the statement itself (it implements [`Traversable`](http://php.net/manual/class.traversable.php)).

Also, you should use parameter binding.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT `nickname` FROM `users` WHERE `number` = ?');
$stmt->execute([$rand_number]);
while($nickname = $stmt->fetchColumn()) {
    echo $nickname;
}
```

Comment: no `number` keyword in reserved words https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html , closest one is `numeric` but yeah the fetching part is missing, or might be truncated in the codes